# Git push to various repositories via bash script

Tags: bash, git, scripting

I'm trying to create a bash script that iterates over 4 different folders (git repositories) and updates/pushes the changes for each one of them. I have the script mostly complete, except the authentication part.

Here's my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fetch username and password
echo "Please insert your git credentials!"
read -p 'Username: ' username
read -sp 'Password: ' password

# Check if you svn and git installed in your machine
if  which svn &> /dev/null && which git &> /dev/null; then

    # Store the current dir
    CUR_DIR=$(pwd)

    # Let the person running the script know what's going on.
    echo "Pulling in latest changes for all repositories..."

    for D in $CUR_DIR/*; do
        if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
            echo "${D}"

            cd $(basename $D);

            # Make sure SVN is on trunk branch and git branch is on master
            SVN_BRANCH=$(svn info | grep '^URL:' | egrep -o '(tags|branches)/[^/]+|trunk' | egrep -o '[^/]+$')
            GIT_BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

            if [ "$SVN_BRANCH"!="trunk" ] || [ "$GIT_BRANCH"!="master" ]; then
                echo $CUR_DIR
                echo "Make sure you're on SVN trunk branch and git master branch."
                exit -1
            fi

            echo "Update SVN repository";
            svn up

            # Update git
            git add .;
            git commit -m "Update with the changes from svn trunk branch."
            echo "Start pushing changes to main repository."
            git push origin master

            echo "Update git repository";
            git pull origin master

            # Update SVN
            svn add .
            svn commit -m "Update with changes from git master branch."

            cd ..
        fi

        echo "Complete!"
    done
else
    echo "You need both svn and git CLI's installed to run this script!";
fi
```

As you can see, I'm already fetching the credentials in the beginning of the script, my problem is how can I use them to do the actions that need authentication, namely

```
git push origin master
git pull origin master
```

How can I build the git commands to make the authenticated request?

Comment: Where do you host your origin?

Comment: They're stored in an Enterprise gitlab server.

Comment: You could try to pipe username/password to the `git pull`/`git push` commands

Comment: What I don't know is how can I build the command to include username/password.

Comment: What kind of remote are you accessing when you run `git push origin ...` ? https ? ssh ?

Comment: side note : you can place the `which svn && which git` at the beginning of your script, and turn it the other way arround : `if ! which svn || ! which git; then echo "You need ..."; exit 1; fi`. That will be one less indentation level for the remainder of your script.

Comment: Try using an ssh key.  You will need to upload the public part via the Git web interface.  Then you can encrypt the private part of your ssh key.

Comment: Using https at the moment, not sure if using ssh will be a possibility.